# deviceready not firing when running my Phonegap app on IceCreamSandwich

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm developing a mobile app using phonegap and jQuery Mobile.
The app works like a charm on iOS and android 2.3 but it unfortunately not on ice cream sandwich (tested on the emulator and on a nexus s as well).
Does anyone has experienced this issue?

I'm using phonegap-1.3.0

the loading code is the following:

```
function onBodyLoad() {
    if ($.browser.webkit) {
        phonegapReady = true;
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    //Phone Gap is ready!
    phonegapReady = true;
    onAllReady();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also seeing the same thing happen with phonegap-1.3.0 + JQM in the android emulator. It doesn't seem like the deviceready is firing. If I call `onDeviceReady()` directly all is well. Currently using this hack:

```
function onBodyLoad() { 

    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ) {
             onDeviceReady();
    } else if (typeof navigator.device == "undefined"){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
             onDeviceReady();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I found out that the issue was due to the fact that $.getScript isn't working properly in a PhoneGap app running on android 4.0

Comment: @PBN: Did you manage to get around the getScript issue? I'm having the same problem with ICS.